# Selecting between task executor with LinkedBlockingQueue and SynchronousQueue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

I currently have a processor implementation that is creating a `ThreadPoolExecutor` using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` as to offer async submissions of incoming jobs/tasks. The intention for this is to offer client an immediate response with some initial response.

The below `TradeProcessor` sits in a common project (say Project A) and is used by other projects (say project B and C):

```
public class TradeProcessor implements Processor {

    private final TestRepository repo;
    private final JobRunner runner;

    private int corePoolSize = 1 //always 1
    private int maxPoolSize = 1; //always 1
    private int keepAliveTime = 60
    private int queueSize = 10;

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public AsyncProcessor(final TestRepository repo, final JobRunner runner) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.runner = runner;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {       
        executorService = createNewThreadPoolExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public MyResponse process(final TestRequest request, final String id) {
      
        executorService.execute(new JobRunTask(runner, repo, Pair.of(id, request)));

        return new MyResponse(request.getName(), id, SUBMITTED, initialJobStatus());
    }

    private ThreadPoolExecutor createNewThreadPoolExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, SECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize),
                                      new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("abc-thread-%d").build(),
                                      createRejectedExecutionHandler()) {
            @Override
            protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
                if (null != t) {
                   //bla bla
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private RejectedExecutionHandler createRejectedExecutionHandler() {
        return (runnable, executor) -> {
            //bla bla
        };
    }
}
```

I am now looking to add some synchronous functionality to the above Processor. For example, A project may  choose that it can **wait** for a response and have the actual full response back and not the initial one. It blocks when task executed/submitted and has the result back and sends response.
I understand I can satisfy this requirement if I create an `ThreadPoolExecutor` using `SynchronousQueue`? How can I implement this and switch between the two modes, sync and async, based on some flags that the individuals projects will provide?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use SynchrnousQueue, you can directly call the method of the JobRunTask to get the response when you want things to happen synchronously.

Processor interface defines three method

```
interface Processor {
    // This will enqueue the request and returns default value
    MyResponse process(final TestRequest request, final String id);
    // this will process request in sync
    MyResponse processSync(final TestRequest request, final String id);
    // this returns a future that can be used to check if the execution is completed or not and also returns a response.
    Future<MyResponse> processAsync(final TestRequest request, final String id);
  }
```

Your JobRunTask class would define two public methods as opposed to one method, in one of the method it will return the response by executing the business logic while in other it will run as a runnable task.

```
  class JobRunTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      MyResponse response = execute();
      // do something with response
    }

    public MyResponse execute() {
      // your business logic
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Once you have these two interfaces handy you can implement your TradeProcessor class as.

```
  public class TradeProcessor implements Processor {
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private final JobRunner runner;
    private final TestRepository repo;

    @Override
    public MyResponse process(final TestRequest request, final String id) {
      executorService.execute(new JobRunTask(runner, repo, Pair.of(id, request)));
      return new MyResponse(request.getName(), id, SUBMITTED, initialJobStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public MyResponse processSync(final TestRequest request, final String id) {
      return new JobRunTask(runner, repo, Pair.of(id, request)).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public Future<MyResponse> processAsync(final TestRequest request, final String id) {
      return executorService.submit(() -> new JobRunTask(runner, repo, Pair.of(id, request)));
    }
  }
```

Other details like initialization/object creations etc have been left for the op.

Using this you would not have to switch from one queue to another. It will also allow the caller to see the request was completed or not, in case the caller runs multiple threads in parallel.

Comment: only `process()` gets invoked by RestController class and that RestController class is given to other projects injected via maven dependency so I can only have `process()`. The idea for `SynchrnousQueue` was that I would use `future.get()` and block so it mimics sync